# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo - FirebaseListAdapter null object

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, chat, firebaseui

I want to do public chat with firebase database to pass classes at the University. I have problem because, I learn how to write this and I watched tutorials on youtube. I found project and I did, but firebase change a few things with FirebaseListAdapter. For that I changed code.

Currently I have this:

I know what's happen (probably) , but I need idea how to fix It.

1) ActivityChat is based on tutorials, on the internet.

```
public class ActivityChat extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMsg> adapter;
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats").limitToLast(50);

    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMsg> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMsg>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatMsg.class)
            .setLayout(R.layout.activity_chat)
            .build();
    EditText input;
    RelativeLayout chat;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pomyślnie zalogowany!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie można zalogować się. Spróbuj później.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        chat = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_chat);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").push().setValue(new ChatMsg(input.getText().toString(),
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
                input.setText("");
                input.requestFocus();
                displayChatMessage();
            }

        });


        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Witaj: " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private void displayChatMessage() {
        ListView listMessage = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMsg>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull ChatMsg model, int position) {
                TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;
                messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };
        listMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

2) When I push button to go to the Chat, I see activity for 2 seconds and I have crash apk (Apk has stopped).

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bsk69.spystreamgui, PID: 6214
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bsk69.spystreamgui/com.example.bsk69.spystreamgui.ActivityChat}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.startListening()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2763)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2824)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.startListening()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bsk69.spystreamgui.ActivityChat.onStart(ActivityChat.java:222)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6792)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2824) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a `NullPointerException` on `ActivityChat.java:222`, which is the last line of your `onStart` method:

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

The error means that you're calling `startListening()` before you've created the `adapter`. Since you only create the adapter in `displayChatMessage` when the user clicks a button, you can blindly tell it to start connecting to the database in `onStart`, which happens before the user clicks the button.

Most likely you can simply start listening straight when you create the adapter:

```
private void displayChatMessage() {
    ListView listMessage = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMsg>(options) {
        ...
    };
    listMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

You'll also need to change the `onStop`, since this may be called without the user every clicking the button. The simplest fix there is:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

These null pointer exceptions are extremely common in programming, so I highly recommend reading [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: Thanks I check It, because I learn writing. Currently I back to my first problem. I did a lot of combinations to fix It. When I write something and push "send button", I have crash, but message is saved in database.I need to see message in my listView:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bsk69.spystreamgui.ActivityChat$2.populateView(ActivityChat.java:209)
        at com.example.bsk69.spystreamgui.ActivityChat$2.populateView(ActivityChat.java:201)

Comment: That's in another location than the one you had earlier. If you follow the steps in the question/answer I linked, you should be able to figure out what object is `null`. You'll need to initialize that object before you call `setText()` on it, similar to what I did for `adapter` in my answer.

Comment: OK, WORKING !
My fail was with layout. I wrote activity_chat.xml, but I should list_item.xml.
<FACEPALM>

Thanks for help again !
Still is working.

Comment: Good to hear. Happy hacking!